# What MySQL collation to select when storing MD5 CHAR(32)?

Tags: mysql, database, encoding, character-encoding, collation

I am storing `MD5 hashes` as indexes of some records, I understand a good data type for this is `CHAR(32)`, but what should I select for `collation` ?

I assume it is relevant that `MD5` only support these characters: `abcdef0123456789` so I need a collation that supports very few characters and no special ones ?

Eider way, which one is best collation ? Many other data rows use `utf8_general_ci` in my db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will you need to have "A" == "a"?  If so, you need a case-folding `COLLATION`.

But first, I suspect your question is really about `CHARACTER SET`.  This is the encoding of the characters.  Almost any character set can handle hex characters.  `ascii` is fine; `latin1` is fine.  I would not use any character sets other than those for MD5, UUID, country_code, postal_code, etc.  And, since each of those is constant length, `CHAR(..)` is useful.  Virtually everywhere else, `VARCHAR(..)` is 'better'.

"Collation" has to do with sorting and comparing.  Once you have decided on `CHARACTER SET ascii` (or latin1), *then* you need to decide whether you will ever need to compare `a1b2` = `A1B2`.  If so, use `ascii_general_ci` (or `latin1_general_ci`).  The "ci" means "case insensitive".

If you will never mix capitalization, `ascii_bin` (`latin1_bin`) is fine and is a *trivial* amount faster.  "bin" means "just compare the bits"; that is, no case folding, accent stripping. etc.

Even better might be to convert from `CHAR(32)` to `BINARY(16)` via `UNHEX()` and go the other way via `HEX()`.  This has no collation and cuts the space used in half.  (But it makes the string unprintable.)

For other columns, ...  The *character set* utf8mb4, not utf8, is needed for Chinese and Emoji (like your picture).  I can't judge whether the _general_ci *collation* is appropriate without understanding more about your application.

Comment: OK, looks like I need to research more on `CHARACTER SET` as I am a bit lost now. Did you miss a verb here ? `I would not any`

Comment: So I understand to store the MD5 values, `latin` character set would do, but if I have a table where I need to save url titles with Chinese characters, there is correct to use an `utf8` character set, no ?

Comment: @adrianTNT - MD5, UUID, country_code, postal_code, etc:  `CHAR(...) CHARACTER SET latin1`; pick the collation based on the need for case-folding.  Chinese:  Better go with `utf8mb4`, some Chinese characters need 4 bytes.  (And I fixed the typo.)

Comment: 2 years later, searched for this on Google, read the page for some time, and then "wow ! it's me, I asked this question" :)))

Comment: @adrianTNT - After 2 years, you now have a more involved Question?

Comment: hmm.. not sure if more involved :D , today when switching from `Mysql 5.7` to `8.0.30` I had this other question, I think I found the answer for that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74687069/is-utf8mb4-0900-ai-ci-a-good-collation-for-general-purpose-in-mysql-8-0-30