# Is utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci a good collation for general purpose in MySQL 8.0.30?

Tags: mysql, database, encoding, character-encoding, collation

For storing and searching trough MySQL data in many different languages, e.g indexing website titles from all domain names...

Would it work ok to use `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` collation ? I see that is what `MySQL 8.0.30` switched to when importing data from older server (`MySQL 5.7`).

- is `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` a default in MySQL 8 ?
- even if not a default, is it generally OK to use `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the default in MySQL 8.0 is utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci. You can check default system settings for yourself, by consulting the manual, e.g.: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_collation_server

Yes, it's a good collation to use in MySQL 8.0. It's what I would choose. It includes the most up to date changes to the UTF standard available in MySQL.